# Idiom for creating a scoped value only once in scala

Tags: scala

Say I define a function that declares a variable in its body thus:

```
def foo = {
 val x = new X()
 x.bar
}
```

Is there a way I can do this such that x is only created once no matter how many times I call the function? In other words can I achieve:

```
val x = new X()
def foo = {
  x.bar
}
```

but keep the definition of x within the scope of the function?

Comment: Do you mean like `lazy val foo = new X`?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the variable in the scope of the function?  The fact that it's state transcends multiple function calls, implies that its scope should be an class variable or object variable.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that. If your variable is declared inside a block B. This variable cannot be seen outside B.

What you can do, is to make a class or an object to make an attribut visible outside of a definition.

```
object CoolObject {
  val x = new X()

  def foo = {
       // [...]
       x.bar
       // [...]
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If `x` is truly singleton, then you need to put it into a singleton context. The Scala way to do this is to create an object.

```
object xHolder {
  val x = new X()
}
...
def foo = {
  import xHolder._
  x.bar
}
```

If `foo` is part of a class that has a companion object, you could put it there as well.